# Recovery messed up after phone discharging with no os

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, sony-xperia-z1

I was trying to install CM12 on my Xperia Z1. The zip didn't appear in the SD card in recovery. I accidentally erased the OS thinking that I needed to remove it, then the phone discharged and now its stuck on the Sony logo and I can't find a way to enter recovery mode again.

Comment: So, are you implying that hardware key combination to boot into [tag:recovery-mode] isn't working?

Comment: Yea. I can enter flashboot and im able to flash a new kernel. i can also enter flashmode. i tryed with Flashtool but i have a Pc Software related driver problem